# RaiseEvent (does not work) versus InvokeMember (works)

Tags: c#, .net, dom-events

I have a C# .NET web browser object that fetches a web page. There is an anchor element on this page. My C# is to click on this element. 
The following did not work:

```
AnchorElement.RaiseEvent("onClick");
```

This worked:

```
AnchorElement.InvokeMember("click");
```

Would anyone have a guess as to why? Thanks!

Comment: *The following did not work*, define "not work". What did it do? Nothing? Give you and error?

Comment: Did you try `AnchorElement.RaiseEvent("click")`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your confusion is that the event you are trying to raise is called `click`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events). Not `onClick`. `onClick` is a *handler* for the `click` event, not the event itself.

So you should be able to do:

```
AnchorElement.RaiseEvent("click");
```

`InvokeMember` works here because HTML elements happen to have a `click` method that is basically just a shortcut for `RaiseEvent("click")`.